# How to use custom icon.dat as property icon?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

i'm currently trying to set a custom icon as property icon. I was able to create a working icon .dat file by using the icon file [from Blender itself](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/lib/resources/) and confirmed that its viable by replacing one of the other icons in blender with it (just overwriting an existing file in the installation):

[image](WIP)

The Problem i'm facing now revolves around a custom header menu i'm creating which i want to use my custom icon for.
Here is a code snippet where i use the "LIGHT_SUN" icon thats shipped with blender:

[image]

```
# Create Button in Header
def draw_vp_button(self, context):
    if bpy.context.preferences.addons[__package__].preferences.enable_view3d_button == True: ###Creates Button only when Preferences say so

        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.prop(context.scene.camera_settings, "enable_ae", icon='LIGHT_SUN', text="")
        sub = row.row(align=True)
        sub.active = context.scene.camera_settings.enable_ae
        sub.popover(panel="VIEW3D_PT_exposure_settings", text="")
    else:
        return
```

I've found this on the blender artists forum:
**[where its possible to use it for a tool icon](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-set-custom-icon-for-workspacetool/1288336/2)** **([project on git](https://github.com/Stromberg90/Scripts/blob/master/Blender/mesh_merge_tool/__init__.py))** which goes in the direction of what i'm trying to do, however i just can't seem to combine it with my code.

From my understanding
`icon_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "icons")`
would define the filepath of where the icon should be found. in my case this would be the addon folder (..)\3.4\scripts\addons\my_addon\icons

now in the example i've found they are able to set the icon of an operator with
`bl_icon = os.path.join(icon_dir, "ops.mesh.merge_tool")`

however, for simple property icons the code differs as far as i know, as its using
`prop(context.scene.my_properties, "my_bool", icon='LIGHT_SUN')`
So i think i need to somehow declare my icon as a different type of icon? Or at least make it somehow usable by "icon"?

I just can't seem to wrap my head around it and get it to work. I'm sure that there is a way as its possible to use the custom icon in an operator as well, i just dont know how.
My goal would be to replace the 'LIGHT_SUN' with an icon of my own creation.

Note, that i'm not looking for a icon.png implementation, i got that to work but the quality of the images is limited so i want to go the "best way".

Thank you very much for your time.